# Woocommerce custom product_type seems not to be saved correctly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating my own plugin for woocommerce and realized, that my custom product_type is not saved when the product has been created or updated. I am sure that the problem is coming from my plugin, but I am not sure where to look at.
Function to add the product_type (according to a post)

```
function extend_woocommerce()
{
    Class WC_Product_Connected_To_General_Product extends WC_Product_Simple
    {
        public function __construct($product)
        {
            $this->product_type = 'connected_to_general_product';
            $this->manage_stock = 'yes';
            parent::__construct($product);
        }
    }
}
```

Class which is called in the plugin

```
Class general_stock {

/**
 * general_stock constructor.
 */
function __construct()
{
    if($this->check_if_woocommerce_is_active()){
     add_action('init',[$this, 'add_woocommerce_product_type'])
     add_filter('product_type_selector', [$this,'add_woocommerce_product_type_general_connected_product']);

...
}
/**
 * add_woocommerce_product_type
 */
function add_woocommerce_product_type(){
    extend_woocommerce();
}
/**
 * add_woocommerce_product_type_general_connected_product
 * @param $types
 * @return mixed
 */
function add_woocommerce_product_type_general_connected_product($types){
    $types[$this->product_type_name] = __('Connected to general Product','ln-general-stock');
    return $types;
}
```

However "everything" works so far: I am able to select the new product type in backend and saving it aswell. (It is selected when I edit the product).

But when I query the Product in frontend and dump it, the value of `product_type` equals `simple` which I think should be `connected_to_general_product` or is this information stored in another value?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I just found out, that the product_type is saved as term through this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355770/woocommerce-in-wordpress-return-always-simple-as-product-type

Comment: Is `$this->product_type_name` defined? If not, then the select element will not have a value to save and WooCommerce will probably save it as `simple`.

Answer (score 9):

Remember the extends of product class name has to start with WP_Product_ followed with the producto type. Eg.:

```
class WC_Product_Moto extends WC_Product {
    protected $product_type = 'moto';

    public function get_type(){
        return 'moto';
    }
}
```

Comment: this solved my problem, I changed MyCustomClass to WC_Product_Mytype

Comment: For reference: The class name is generated from the product type as follows: `'WC_Product_' . implode( '_', array_map( 'ucfirst', explode( '-', $product_type ) ) )`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73230764/1878199

Answer (score 2):

Also, add this code if doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_class', array($this,'load_custom_product_type_class'), 10, 2 );

    public function load_custom_product_type_class( $classname, $product_type ){
        if ( $product_type == 'your_custom_product_type_here' ) {
            $classname = 'YOUR_PRODUCT_TYPE_CLASS_NAME';
        }
        return $classname;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably re-arrange the structure of your plugin a bit. I like to load the plugin on the `woocommerce_loaded` plugin, then you don't even need a conditional check to see if WooCommerce is active.  But I think the problem is the array key/value pair that you are adding to the `product_type_selector` filter.

```
Class general_stock {

    /**
     * pseudo constructor.
     */
    public static function init()
    {
        include_once( 'path-to/class-wc-product-connected-to-general-product.php' );
         add_filter('product_type_selector', array( __CLASS__, 'add_woocommerce_product_type_general_connected_product' ) );
    }

    ...


    /**
     * add_woocommerce_product_type_general_connected_product
     * @param $types
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function add_woocommerce_product_type_general_connected_product($types){
        $types['general-product'] = __('Connected to general Product','ln-general-stock');
        return $types;
    }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', 'general_stock::init');
```

---

```
Class WC_Product_Connected_To_General_Product extends WC_Product_Simple
{
    public function __construct($product)
    {
        $this->product_type = 'connected_to_general_product';
        $this->manage_stock = 'yes';
        parent::__construct($product);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that I had to define a missing function in my case

```
if (class_exists('WC_Product_Simple')) {
    class WC_Product_Ebook_Store extends WC_Product_Simple {

    public function __construct( $product ) {

        $this->product_type = 'ebook_store';

        parent::__construct( $product );

    }
    public function get_type() {
        return 'ebook_store';
    }

    }
}
```