# Add a new product type in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce, product

In Woocommerce, I have created a custom product type `live_stream`.

But when I create a new product within this custom type and I publish it, the product remains a "simple product" and doesn't get the `live_stream` custom type set for it.

What I am doing wrong? How to make that custom product type functional?

Here is my code

```
function wpstream_register_live_stream_product_type() {
    class Wpstream_Product_Live_Stream extends WC_Product {
        public function __construct( $product ) {

            $this->product_type = 'live_stream';
            parent::__construct( $product );

        }

        public function get_type() {
            return 'live_stream';
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpstream_register_live_stream_product_type' );

function wpstream_add_products( $types ){
    $types[ 'live_stream' ]             = __( 'Live Channel','wpestream' );
    return $types;
}
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'wpstream_add_products' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Woocommerce 3 `$this->product_type = 'live_stream';` is deprecated and not needed in the constructor. It has to be replaced by defining the function `get_type()` outside the constructor in the Class for this custom product type.

So your code will be:

```
add_action( 'init', 'new_custom_product_type' );
function new_custom_product_type(){
    class WC_Product_Live_Stream extends WC_Product{

        public function __construct( $product ) {
            parent::__construct( $product );
        }

        // Needed since Woocommerce version 3
        public function get_type() {
            return 'live_stream';
        }
    }
}

add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'custom_product_type_to_type_selector' );
function custom_product_type_to_type_selector( $types ){
    $types[ 'live_stream' ] = __( 'Live Channel', 'wpestream' );
    return $types;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, @LoicTheAztec,
I am trying to write plugin code in PSR4 with namespaces, how can i  create r call a class inside a function?

Comment: @MilindSingh I don't know anything about PSR4 so your question should be asked in StackOverFlow something like: *"How can I create r call in a PHP class inside a function"* (but not specifically for Woocommerce or wordpress)…

Answer (score 0):

I was debugging this as well. I use namespaces, so I was considering that this is part of the problem. It is not. So for future (and other people's) reference.

The class lookup happens in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-factory.php`:

```
/**
 * Create a WC coding standards compliant class name e.g. WC_Product_Type_Class instead of WC_Product_type-class.
 *
 * @param  string $product_type Product type.
 * @return string|false
 */
public static function get_classname_from_product_type( $product_type ) {
    return $product_type ? 'WC_Product_' . implode( '_', array_map( 'ucfirst', explode( '-', $product_type ) ) ) : false;
}
```

You can use this snippet (or set a breakpoint on debugging) to determine why your `$product-type`does not resolve to the correct classname.

In my case I had a product name like `my_class` and thought mistakenly it would resolve to `My_Class`, which it does not, it resolves to `My_class`.

Comment: While namespaces are not the issue OP was facing, they are definitely an issue where you have to filter them into the `get_product_classname()` method otherwise it returns an non-namespaced version