# Showing Custom WooCommerce Product Types in WCFM Vendor Manager Add Product Screen

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have created custom product types in WooCommerce, but they are not pulling through into WCFM.

I have the option of adding these new custom product types as filters in the add product and vendor capabilities screens in WCFM, but this is just a cosmetic change with linkage to the custom product types I created in WooCommerce. Because it is only cosmetic I can set the permissions for a vendor to only be able to select a specific product type but when they go to the add product page they see all of the custom product types (as the drop-down is in no way linked to their permissions)

The code I have used to make the custom types visible in WCFM is below. I realize now how useless this is unless it is making reference to the custom product types created in WooCommerce.

```php
add_filter( 'wcfm_product_types', function( $pro_types ) {
$pro_types['LPM'] = __( 'Lego Party Machinery', 'woocommerce' );
    return $pro_types;
}, 50 );

//Adds toggle to vendor custom capabilities
add_filter( 'wcfm_capability_settings_fields_product_types', function( $prod_types, $capability_handler, $capability_manager_options ) {
    $new_product = ( isset( $capability_manager_options['LPM'] ) ) ? $capability_manager_options['LPM'] : 'no';
    $prod_types['LPM'] = array('label' => __('LPM', 'wc-frontend-manager') , 'name' => $capability_handler.'[LPM]','type' => 'checkboxoffon', 'class' => 'wcfm-checkbox wcfm_ele', 'value' => 'no', 'label_class' => 'wcfm_title checkbox_title', 'dfvalue' => $new_product);
    return $prod_types;
}, 50, 3 );
```

I used [this tutorial for the custom product types](https://webkul.com/blog/create-a-custom-product-type-in-woocommerce/):

How can I get WCFM displaying the Product Types in WooCommerce rather than creating custom filters in WCFM that are independent.

Comment: Your tutorial for custom product type is outdated, since WooCommerce 3, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49336478/3730754)…